# Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation) - method authentication (create user with email and password)

Tags: typescript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm developing an application with authentication in firebase with Expo, Basically, I have an authentication hook, a registration screen with a form in steps. In my component that represents the last step, it receives a Promise in which it makes the call to the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method.

What I found curious is that when I run it in the original way, the communication with firebase triggers the error, but when I call it directly on the parent component (RegisterScreen), it doesn't trigger the error and the registration flows normally.

Why does it happen?

Here's my code:

```
// my hook auth.tsx

import { createContext, useState, useContext, ReactNode } from 'react';

import { auth } from '../services/firebase';
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
} from 'firebase/auth';

type AuthContextType = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  user: User | null;
  token: string;
  signUpEmailAndPassword: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
  signOut: () => Promise<void>;
}

type User = {
  uid: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  emailVerified: boolean;
  photo?: string;
}

type SignInEmailAndPasswordData = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

type AuthProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextType);

function AuthProvider({ children }: AuthProviderProps) {
  const [ user, setUser ] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [ token, setToken ] = useState('');

  const isAuthenticated = !!user;

  async function signUpEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string) {
    try {
      const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      console.log(user);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      
    }
  }

  async function signOut() {}

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{
      isAuthenticated,
      user,
      token,
      signUpEmailAndPassword,
      signOut,
    }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useAuth() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);

  return context
}

export { AuthProvider, useAuth }
```

```
// my firebaseConfig

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const { API_KEY } = process.env;
const { AUTH_DOMAIN } = process.env;
const { PROJECT_ID } = process.env;
const { STORAGE_BUCKET } = process.env;
const { MESSAGING_SENDER_ID } = process.env;
const { APP_ID } = process.env;
const { MEASUREMENT_ID } = process.env;

export const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

```
// my screen component Register.tsx

import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { BottomSheetModal } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';

import { Button } from '../../components/Button';

import { CpfStep } from '../../components/FormSteps/SignUpSteps/CpfStep';
import { FullNameStep } from '../../components/FormSteps/SignUpSteps/FullNameStep';
import { BornDate } from '../../components/FormSteps/SignUpSteps/BornDateStep';
import { EmailStep } from '../../components/FormSteps/SignUpSteps/EmailStep';
import { CellPhone } from '../../components/FormSteps/SignUpSteps/CellPhone';
import { PasswordStep } from '../../components/FormSteps/SignUpSteps/PasswordStep';
import { ValidationSmsStep } from '../../components/FormSteps/SignUpSteps/ValidationSmsStep';
import {
  ValidationSignUpOptionStep
} from '../../components/FormSteps/SignUpSteps/ValidationSignUpOptionStep';

import { useAuth } from '../../hooks/auth';

import ArrowLeftSvg from '../../assets/icons/arrow-left.svg';

import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Main,
  ModalContent,
  TitleHeader,
  TitleModal,
} from './styles';

type DataProps = {
  cpf: string;
  fullName: string;
  bornDate: string;
  email: string;
  cellPhone: string;
  password: string;
  confirmPassword: string;
  codeValidation: string;
}

interface Steps {
  id: string;
  isShow: boolean;
  component: () => JSX.Element;
}

export function SignUpWithEmail() {
  const modalSuccessRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);

  const [ data, setData ] = useState<DataProps>({} as DataProps);
  const [ steps, setSteps ] = useState<Steps[]>([
    {
      id: 'cpfStep',
      isShow: true,
      component: () => (
        <CpfStep
          onNextStep={handleNextStep}
          onUpdateData={handleUpdateData}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      id: 'fullNameStep',
      isShow: false,
      component: () => (
        <FullNameStep
          onNextStep={handleNextStep}
          onUpdateData={handleUpdateData}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      id: 'bornDate',
      isShow: false,
      component: () => (
        <BornDate
          onNextStep={handleNextStep}
          onUpdateData={handleUpdateData}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      id: 'emailStep',
      isShow: false,
      component: () => (
        <EmailStep
          onNextStep={handleNextStep}
          onUpdateData={handleUpdateData}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      id: 'cellPhone',
      isShow: false,
      component: () => (
        <CellPhone
          onNextStep={handleNextStep}
          onUpdateData={handleUpdateData}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      id: 'passwordStep',
      isShow: false,
      component: () => (
        <PasswordStep
          onNextStep={handleNextStep}
          onUpdateData={handleUpdateData}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      id: 'validationSignUpOptionStep',
      isShow: false,
      component: () => (
        <ValidationSignUpOptionStep
          onNextStep={handleNextStep}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      id: 'validationSmsStep',
      isShow: false,
      component: () => (
        <ValidationSmsStep
          onUpdateData={handleUpdateData}
          onRegisterNewUser={handleRegisterInFirebase}
        />
      )
    },
  ]);

  const { goBack } = useNavigation();

  const { signUpEmailAndPassword } = useAuth();

  async function handleRegisterInFirebase() {
    try {
      await signUpEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  function handleUpdateData(value: any) {
    setData(state => (
      {
        ...state,
        ...value
      }
    ));
  }

  function handleNextStep(stepId: string) {
    setSteps(state => state.map((step) => {
      if(step.id === stepId) {
        return {
          ...step,
          isShow: true,
        }
      }

      return {
        ...step,
        isShow: false,
      }
    }));
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <Button
          rounded
          color="secondary"
          onPress={goBack}
        >
          <ArrowLeftSvg
            height={18}
            width={18}
          />
        </Button>
        <TitleHeader>Cadastro</TitleHeader>
      </Header>

      <Main>
        {steps.map(step => (
          step.isShow && <step.component key={step.id} />
        ))}
      </Main>

      <BottomSheetModal
        ref={modalSuccessRef}
        snapPoints={['30%', '30%']}
      >
        <ModalContent>
          <TitleModal>
            Cadastro realizado com sucesso
          </TitleModal>
        </ModalContent>
      </BottomSheetModal>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

```
// my last component form step

import React from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as yup from 'yup';

import { Button } from '../../../Button';
import { InputCodeForm } from '../../../Form/InputCodeForm';

import {
  Container,
  Form,
  SubTitle,
  Title,
} from './styles';

interface IForm {
  codeValidation: string;
}

interface Props {
  onUpdateData: (value: any) => void;
  onRegisterNewUser: () => Promise<void>;
}

const schema = yup.object({
  codeValidation: yup
    .string()
    .required('Campo obrigatório'),
});

export function ValidationSmsStep({
  onUpdateData,
  onRegisterNewUser,
}: Props) {
  const {
    control,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit
  } = useForm<IForm>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  async function handleSubmitStep(data: IForm) {
    onUpdateData(data);

    await onRegisterNewUser();
  }

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <Container>
        <Form>
          <Title>Digite o código enviado por SMS</Title>
          <SubTitle>
            (00)00000-0000
          </SubTitle>

          <InputCodeForm
            name="codeValidation"
            control={control}
            cellsNumber={6}
            error={errors.codeValidation && errors.codeValidation.message}
          />
        </Form>

        <Button
          title="Continuar"
          colorTitle="secondary"
          onPress={handleSubmit(handleSubmitStep)}
        />
      </Container>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}
```

error firebase:

```
Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).
at node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:326:27 in Provider#shouldAutoInitialize
at node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.esm2017.js:508:0 in <global>
at node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.esm2017.js:536:20 in createMockUserToken
at node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:308:33 in <anonymous>
at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/rn/phone-eec7f987.js:340:0 in <global>
at node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/index.cjs.js:41:22 in <anonymous>
at http://192.168.0.105:19000/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:159385:21 in <unknown>
at http://192.168.0.105:19000/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:159339:31 in fulfilled
```

Comment: Any explication for this? I have the exact same behaviour, when i call createUserWithEmailAndPassword on it's own, it works without issues, if i however couple it with a fetch.. it fails with this error code